# pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: ("Could not convert 'col_x' with type str: tried to convert to double", 'Conversion failed for column with type object')

Tags: pandas, oracle, schema, parquet, pyarrow

While enforcing pyarrrow schema on a pandas dataframe (to create a parquet file of the same), there is a number(24,3) datatype column coming from Oracle which is not being typecasted and it is throwing this error:

> pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: ("Could not convert 'col_x' with type str: tried to convert to double", 'Conversion failed for column with type object')

P.S. I have used float64() for typecasting the float value in pyarrow.

I have tried float64, float32, decimal128 and decimal256.

these are the package versions installed:
pandas :  2.0.1,
pyarrow : 12.0.0,
cx_Oracle: 8.3.0